# Java Counting # of occurrences of a word in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a large text file I am reading from and I need to find out how many times some words come up.  For example, the word `the`.  I'm doing this line by line each line is a string.

I need to make sure that I only count legit `the`'s--the `the` in `other` would not count.  This means I know I need to use regular expressions in some way.  What I was trying so far is this:

```
numSpace += line.split("[^a-z]the[^a-z]").length;
```

I realize the regular expression may not be correct at the moment but I tried without that and just tried to find occurrences of the word `the` and I get wrong numbers too.  I was under the impression this would split the string up into an array and how many times that array was split up was how many times the word is in the string.  Any ideas I would be grateful.

Update:
Given some ideas, I've come up with this:

```
numThe += line.split("[^a-zA-Z][Tt]he[^a-zA-Z]", -1).length - 1;
```

Though still getting some strange numbers.  I was able to get an accurate general count (without the regular expression), now my issue is with the regexp.

Comment: I don't agree that you have to use regular expressions I'm just wondering why you are using the regex?

Comment: `Though still getting some strange numbers.` sounds interesting. Would you like to talk about it? Maybe report whether those numbers are astonishing big, or curiously low?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `split` to count isn't the most efficient, but if you insist on doing that, the proper way is this:

```
haystack.split(needle, -1).length -1
```

If you don't set `limit` to `-1`, `split` defaults to `0`, which removes trailing empty strings, which messes up your count.

From [the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. [...] If `n` is zero then [...] trailing empty strings will be discarded.

You also need to subtract 1 from the `length` of the array, because `N` occurrences of the delimiter splits the string into `N+1` parts.

---

As for the regex itself (i.e. the `needle`), you can use `\b` the word boundary anchors around the `word`. If you allow `word` to contain metacharacters (e.g. count occurrences of `"$US"`), you may want to [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) it.

---

> I've come up with this:
>
> ```
> numThe += line.split("[^a-zA-Z][Tt]he[^a-zA-Z]", -1).length - 1;
> ```
>
> Though still getting some strange numbers. I was able to get an accurate general count (without the regular expression), now my issue is with the regexp.

Now the issue is that you're not counting `[Tt]he` that appears as the first or last word, because the regex says that it has to be preceded/followed by some character, something that matches `[^a-zA-Z]` (that is, your match must be of length 5!). You're not allowing the case where there *isn't* a character at all!

You can try something like this instead:

```
"(^|[^a-zA-Z])[Tt]he([^a-zA-Z]|$)"
```

This isn't the most concise solution, but it works.

Something like this (using [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) also works:

```
"(?<![a-zA-Z])[Tt]he(?![^a-zA-Z])"
```

This has the benefit of matching *just* `[Tt]he`, without any extra characters around it like your previous solution did. This is relevant in case you actually want to process the tokens returned by `split`, because the delimiter in this case isn't "stealing" anything from the tokens.

---

#### Non-`split`

Though using `split` to count is rather convenient, it isn't the most efficient (e.g. it's doing all kinds of work to return those strings that you discard). The fact that as you said you're counting line-by-line means that the pattern would also have to be recompiled and thrown away every line.

A more efficient way would be to use the same regex you did before and do the usual `Pattern.compile` and `while (matcher.find()) count++;`

Comment: Reading through the documents and then spitting out my results line by line to see where it's not seeing my words my search of :
"[^a-zA-Z][Tt]he[^a-zA-Z]"
Does not count any 'the' that starts at the beginning of the string.  Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 5):

To get the number of occurrence of a specific word use the below code

```
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Thewordyouwant");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        int count = 0;
        while(matcher.find())
            count++;
```

Comment: Is there a one liner for replacing         while(matcher.find())
            count++; ?

Answer (score 4):

Why not run your line through the Java [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) then you can get the words broken up by not just spaces but also commas and other punctuation. Just run through your tokens and count the occurrence of each "the" or any word you would like.

It would be very easy to expand this a bit and make a map that had each word as a key and kept a count of each word use. Also you may need to consider running each word through a function to [stem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) the word so you can count a more useful thing then just the words.

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the Strings sounds like a lot of overhead just to find out the number of occurrences in a file. You could use `String.indexOf(String, int)` to recursively go through the whole line/file, like this:

```
int occurrences = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index < s.length() && (index = s.indexOf("the", index)) >= 0) {
    occurrences++;
    index + 3; //length of 'the'
}
```

Comment: This loops forever unless you add index++ within the loop body.

Comment: @mchr Right! Basic mistakes.. maybe it now works more correctly

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an area where unit tests can really help. I had a similar thing some time ago where I wanted to break a string up in a number of complex ways and create a number of tests, each of which tested against a different source string, helped me to isolate the regex and also quickly see when I got it wrong.

Certainly if you gave us an example of a test string and the result it would help us to give you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the word boundary \b in the regex:

```
\bthe\b
```

Also the size of the array returned by the `split` will be 1 more than the actual number of occurrences of the word the in the `string`.

Comment: You also need to set `limit` to a negative number for `split`; otherwise it will discard trailing empty strings (e.g. `"the".split("\\bthe\\b").length == 0`; if you use limit `-1` it returns `2` as expected (i.e. one more than the number of occurrences as you pointed out).

Comment: You really don’t want to use `\b` in Java regexes.  [It just doesn’t work. :-(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261).

Answer (score 0):

Search for " the " using [boyer-moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) [in the remainder of the string after a hit] and count number of occurences?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class OccurenceOfWords {
 public static void main(String args[]){    
   String file = "c:\\customer1.txt";
   TreeMap <String ,Integer> index = new TreeMap();

    String []list = null;
      try(    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);//using arm jdk 7.0 feature
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr))
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line!= null){
                list = line.split("[ \n\t\r:;',.(){}]");
                for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length;i++)
                {
                  String word = list[i].toLowerCase();  
                    if(word.length() != 0)
                    {
                        if(index.get(word)== null)
                        { index.put(word,1);
                         }
                        else    
                        {
                            int occur = index.get(word).intValue();
                            occur++;
                            index.put(word, occur);
                        }
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }  
                }
         }}
                         catch(Exception ex){
                       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                       }
                    for(String item : index.keySet()){
                        int repeats = index.get(item).intValue();
                       System.out.printf("\n%10s\t%d",item,repeats);
                 }   
             }               
  }
```

Comment: The longest solution so far. Would you mind explaining what the difference is to other solution, why you think your solution, 2 years later, is that important?

Comment: i am a great fan of stackoverflow and programming a friend of mine who is literally new to java asked me for a solution to count the occurences of words in a text file using java and i readily suggested stackoverflow he said the information was not sufficient for him to build a program of his own and asked help i felt the same so gave an example rightly to my friend and many like him.