# String searching algorithm

Tags: java, string, search

Can someone recommend me a good code/algorithm for string searching?

I'm using Java.

Example: How many times the word apple appears in a text.

Comment: Just a note, algorithms do not necessary depend upon the language.  What you want is a good implementation as others have hinted at in the answers section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try calling method `countMatches(source,word)` of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`.

A small example:

```
      String string = "How arer you? Who are you?";  
      System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(string,"you"));
```

Also look at this thread: [Java Counting # of occurrences of a word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635082/java-counting-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

[This guy](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/) has gone to the trouble of implementing some advanced String search algorithms in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [regexp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: +1, beat me to the generic answer first.

Answer (score 0):

Several algorithms are detailed on the wikipedia [string searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) page. I'd question whether you should be looking at string searching algorithms or just using the functionality already provided by the language.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) page if you are looking for more advanced algorithms.