# How to count number of times a word is used in a text?

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of times a certain word is used in a piece of text, which is `String text`. Do I have to create a new method

```
public int countWords(....) {

}
```

Or is there any ready thing in Java?
Thanks

Comment: already answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635082/java-counting-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string

Comment: this sounds like a job for regular expressions

Comment: Use `StringUtils.countMatches()` in Apache Commons Lang. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StringUtils.countMatches` like so:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("abcdea","a");
```

Here is the [reference](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Well, in that case you could use Regex to solve your problem. Use the `Matcher` class:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("YOUR_REGEX_HERE");
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher("YOUR_TEXT_HERE");

int count = 0;
while (myMatcher.find())
    count ++;
```

Comment: Its part of apache. We would need to add the specific jar.

Comment: Who downvoted me? Mind explaining why?

Comment: PS: i did not downvote. i upvoted and accepted the answer

Comment: There you go: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That is the best and the fastest way !!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using pure Java:

```
public static int countOccurences(String text, String word) {
  int occurences = 0;
  int lastIndex = text.indexOf(word);
  while (lastIndex != -1) {
    occurences++;
    lastIndex = text.indexOf(word, lastIndex + word.length());
  }
  return occurences;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But why do you use `lastIndex != -1` ...

Comment: i tried this, and it appers that i got an infinite loop

Comment: Yes, that results in infinite loop. You need to substring in the loop to make it work.

Comment: @Buras I have tested it and it worked properly. How are you using it?

Comment: @GV Substring in loop is a very good solution ... for writing a completely inefficient code.

Comment: Nevermind my comments... was reading the wrong method description

Answer (score 1):

This may be over complicating it, but,

We could use a `StringTokenizer` to tokenize the `String text`  based on spaces as your delimiter.

You'd use the `nextToken()` method to grab each word and compare it with your search term.

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter = 0;
while(myString.contains("textLookingFor")){
myString.replaceFirst("textLookingFor","");
counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("word");
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher("word");

int count = 0;
while (myMatcher.find()){
    count ++;
}
```