# How to count the characters in a String that matched a given Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Given an arbitrary `String` that contains `0` or more Substrings that **match** a *regular expression*.

How can I count the number of characters in that `String` that were part of Substrings that matched the regex?

*Example:*

Given a regex that matches any email address and the String:

```
"I have two email addresses: email@gmail.com and email@hotmail.com"
```

This would return the int value of `32` (the number of characters in `"email@gmail.com"` plus `"email@hotmail.com"`).

I'm not being clear enough, it seems. Let's pretend you want to set a limit to the number of characters in a tweet, but you want to allow people to include their email address in the tweet and have it count as zero characters.

Possible method signature of solution:

```
public int lengthOfSubStringsMatchingRegex(String input, String regex)
```

Comment: I know how to get the length of an arbitrary String.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635082/java-counting-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string

Comment: Not a duplicate in that I'm not asking for the number of occurrences of a String, I'm looking for the length of all Strings that match a regex in my input String. But that question does have some useful information relative to this in it.

Comment: All match objects contain a method to get the length. It's probably length().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop over the matching groups of your Regex, and use `length()` to extract the number of characters. Add them to your counter, and that's it.

```
public int lengthOfSubStringsMatchingRegex(String input, String regex)
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    int count = 0;
    while (m.find())
        count += m.group().length();

    return count;
}
```

As an alternative, but slightly less readable, you can use directly the offsets:

```
count += m.end() - m.start();
```

*start()* returns the start index of the previous match.
*end()* returns the offset after the last character matched.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 9+

Here's a single-statement stream-based solution.

Since Java 9 we can use [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) that produces a stream of match results `Stream<MatchResult>` *"for each subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern"*.

Then we can transform `MatchResult` into a captured group and find out its length. To obtain the final value, we just need to add up the elements.

```
public static int lengthOfSubStringsMatchingRegex(String input, String regex) {
    
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input) // produces a Matcher
        .results()                // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(MatchResult::group)  // Stream<String>
        .mapToInt(String::length) // IntStream
        .sum();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(lengthOfSubStringsMatchingRegex("a_!_b__c_d_e", "\\p{Punct}+"));
    System.out.println(lengthOfSubStringsMatchingRegex("_?_a_b__c_de_", "\\p{Punct}+"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
7
8
```